# Reading csv flie with commas in R that stops fread function

Tags: r, csv, fread

I am trying to read multiple csv files (like 300) with the function fread in R.

When i open one of the csv files in excel, the columns are delimited correctly, even when some observations contain commas.

When I try to read one of the files, the fuction does't read all the observations in the file and the next error appears

```
> file_prueba<-fread("Datos/Datos_precios/INP_PP_CAB18 (7)_A_vivienda_06_2020.csv", skip = 5, header = TRUE)

Warning message:
In fread("Datos/Datos_precios/INP_PP_CAB18 (7)_A_vivienda_06_2020.csv",  :
  Stopped early on line 1073. Expected 17 fields but found 22. Consider fill=TRUE and comment.char=. First discarded non-empty line: <<"2020","06","20/07/2020 12:00:00 a. m.","12","San Luis Potosí, S.L.P.","3. Vivienda","3.1. Costo de uso de vivienda","3.1.1. Costo de uso de vivienda","42 Vivienda propia","140","Productos para reparación menor de la vivienda","001","PLOMERIA, TUBO DE PVC, REFORZADO, 4", PZA 6 MTS","231.55","1","PZA","">>
```

Therefore i can't read the whole file. I suspect it is because one of the observations cointains commas like "PLOMERIA, TUBO DE COBRE, DE 60 MTS". But I'm not sure.

How can i fix this without fixing each csv file one by one?

Here's the file that i'm using int he example, but as I said, i need to read multiple files like this:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gSjyL14sZQC5KNtMXhN_iN79xCETTZAG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If your file is comma-delimited and you have commas in the data as well, then you will not be able to read the CSV properly. In such a case, the data should be surrounded with quotes

Comment: Could you share the first 10 (non-skipped) lines of the problem file so we have more context?

Comment: Parsing unquoted data line-by-line could be a PITA. If you have a way to reformat the data like @randr recommended, it would be ideal.

Comment: (1) Not reproducible. When I do `fread(text='...\n', header=FALSE)` on that string, it parses into 17 fields, not 19. Perhaps there's a locale problem. (2) You included the literal `comment.char=.`, which is a misunderstanding of their poorly-framed warning message. They aren't saying to include the literal `comment.char=.`, they are suggesting that you set `comment.char` to something, and then the sentence ends and they place a period. It's a bit inconsistent. For me, the literal `comment.char=.` produces an "unused argument", as it is not for `fread` but instead for `read.table` and friends.

Comment: I included the lik to the file that i use in the example. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @randr But if it's comma delimited, why can I read it correctly in excel but nor in R? I also thougth it has something to do with the encoding of the file.... But i don't really know. :/

Comment: The issue is that the file is broken, as @randr just pointed out in their comment. I suggest you go to the origin of the file and request that they re-export it, as it is corrupted in its current state.

Answer (score 1):

The file is corrupt in two ways: lines 1073 and 3401 have embedded quotes. But there's another problem here ... read down to the second section **`fread` and double-double-quotes** for the problem with `fread`.

(Ultimately, this is a failure of the exporting process *and* a failure of `fread` to read embedded double quotes.)

### Corrupted lines

Scroll right to see the problems.

- Line 1073:

  ```
  "2020","06","20/07/2020 12:00:00 a. m.","12","San Luis Potosí, S.L.P.","3. Vivienda","3.1. Costo de uso de vivienda","3.1.1. Costo de uso de vivienda","42 Vivienda propia","140","Productos para reparación menor de la vivienda","001","PLOMERIA, TUBO DE PVC, REFORZADO, 4", PZA 6 MTS","231.55","1","PZA",""
      --->                --->                --->                --->                --->                --->                --->                --->                --->                --->                --->                --->                --->                     ^-- this quote is incorrect
  ```
- Line 3401:

  ```
  "2020","06","20/07/2020 12:00:00 a. m.","43","Campeche, Camp.","3. Vivienda","3.1. Costo de uso de vivienda","3.1.1. Costo de uso de vivienda","42 Vivienda propia","140","Productos para reparación menor de la vivienda","003","NACOBRE, PLOMERIA, TUBO DE COBRE, BARRA DE 1/2" X 6 MT","316.76","1","PZA",""
          --->                        --->                        --->                        --->                        --->                        --->                        --->                        --->                        --->                        --->        ^-- this quote is incorrect
  ```

The best fix is to get whatever person/process exported this to export compliant CSV.

Here is a command-line (`sed`) fix that will allow `fread` to load it without warning or error (this is on a shell prompt, not in R).

```
sed -i \
  -e 's/", PZA/"", PZA/g' \
  -e s'/BARRA DE 1\/2"/BARRA DE 1\/2""/g' \
  "INP_PP_CAB18 (7)_A_vivienda_06_2020.CSV"
```

Simple explanation: the CSV standard (well-framed at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) suggests that either double-quotes should never be in a quoted field, or if present they should be doubled (as in `""` to produce a single `"` in the middle of a value).

In this case, it finds the two *very specific* failing text and adds the second quote.

- `-i` means to make the change *in-place*; perhaps a more defensive use would be to do `sed -e 's/../../g' -e 's/../../g' < oldfile.csv > newfile.csv`, which would preserve the broken file. Over to you.
- `-e` adds a sed script/command, multiple commands can be given.
- `s/from/to/g` means to replace the pattern `from` with the string in `to`; the `g` means "global".

This changes the two lines (shown one after the other here for simplicity:

```r
"2020","06","20/07/2020 12:00:00 a. m.","12","San Luis Potosí, S.L.P.","3. Vivienda","3.1. Costo de uso de vivienda","3.1.1. Costo de uso de vivienda","42 Vivienda propia","140","Productos para reparación menor de la vivienda","001","PLOMERIA, TUBO DE PVC, REFORZADO, 4"", PZA 6 MTS","231.55","1","PZA",""
"2020","06","20/07/2020 12:00:00 a. m.","43","Campeche, Camp.","3. Vivienda","3.1. Costo de uso de vivienda","3.1.1. Costo de uso de vivienda","42 Vivienda propia","140","Productos para reparación menor de la vivienda","003","NACOBRE, PLOMERIA, TUBO DE COBRE, BARRA DE 1/2"" X 6 MT","316.76","1","PZA",""
    --->                --->                --->                --->                --->                --->                --->                --->                --->                --->                --->                --->                --->                     ^^^^^-- the changes, double-double quotes
```

FYI: if you don't have `sed` in the path ... if you're running windows, then look in the RTools40 path; for me, I have `c:/rtools40/usr/bin/sed.exe`. If you're on macos or linux and cannot find `sed`, well ... that's odd.

After that `sed` command executes correctly, it will load without problem. ***HOWEVER***, don't let this mislead you ... it is not really fixed. Keep reading.

```r
csv <- fread("INP_PP_CAB18 (7)_A_vivienda_06_2020.CSV", skip = 5)
csv
#         Año   Mes             Fecha_Pub_DOF Clave ciudad                 Nombre ciudad    División
#       <int> <int>                    <char>        <int>                        <char>      <char>
#    1:  2020     6 20/07/2020 12:00:00 a. m.            1 Área Met. de la Cd. de México 3. Vivienda
#    2:  2020     6 20/07/2020 12:00:00 a. m.            1 Área Met. de la Cd. de México 3. Vivienda
#    3:  2020     6 20/07/2020 12:00:00 a. m.            1 Área Met. de la Cd. de México 3. Vivienda
...snip...
# 11 variables not shown: [Grupo <char>, Clase <char>, Subclase <char>, Clave genérico <int>, Genérico <char>, Consecutivo <int>, Especificación <char>, Precio promedio <num>, Cantidad <int>, Unidad <char>, ...]
```

### `fread` and double-double-quotes

The problem with the above is that while it seems to have worked correctly, it ([still](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4779)) does not do embedded quotes correctly. As long as you want your data to have all of the embedded quotes that you want, then *you cannot use `fread`*, unfortunately.

Why?

```r
str(csv[1067,])
# Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':    1 obs. of  17 variables:
#  $ Año            : int 2020
#  $ Mes            : int 6
#  $ Fecha_Pub_DOF  : chr "20/07/2020 12:00:00 a. m."
#  $ Clave ciudad   : int 12
#  $ Nombre ciudad  : chr "San Luis Potosí, S.L.P."
#  $ División       : chr "3. Vivienda"
#  $ Grupo          : chr "3.1. Costo de uso de vivienda"
#  $ Clase          : chr "3.1.1. Costo de uso de vivienda"
#  $ Subclase       : chr "42 Vivienda propia"
#  $ Clave genérico : int 140
#  $ Genérico       : chr "Productos para reparación menor de la vivienda"
#  $ Consecutivo    : int 1
#  $ Especificación : chr "PLOMERIA, TUBO DE PVC, REFORZADO, 4\"\", PZA 6 MTS"
#  $ Precio promedio: num 232
#  $ Cantidad       : int 1
#  $ Unidad         : chr "PZA"
#  $ Estatus        : chr ""
#  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Namely, see

```r
csv$Especificación[1067]
# [1] "PLOMERIA, TUBO DE PVC, REFORZADO, 4\"\", PZA 6 MTS"
                                          ^^^^ should only be a single "
```

Fortunately, `read.csv` works fine here:

```r
csv <- read.csv("INP_PP_CAB18 (7)_A_vivienda_06_2020.CSV", skip = 5)
csv$Especificación[1067]
# [1] "PLOMERIA, TUBO DE PVC, REFORZADO, 4\", PZA 6 MTS"
```

FYI, if you don't care about the embedded quotes, you can still use `fread` if you change the `sed` expressions to remove the double-quotes instead of doubling the double-quotes. That is, `-e 's/", PZA/, PZA/g'` and likewise for the second expression. I didn't recommend this first because it changes your data, which you should not have to do.

Answer (score 0):

The file you linked is properly quoted.
It has 5 lines of non-CSV data though, so skip these:

```
csv = read.csv("INP_PP_CAB18 (7)_A_vivienda_06_2020.CSV", header = T, skip = 5, fileEncoding = "Latin1")
```

This works fine for me.
I am not so familiar with `fread`, and it does seem to have a problem with this file. Is there a reason you need `data.table::fread` for this?

Comment: There is actually a problem with the file. On line 1067 for example there is an extra `"` character. ("PLOMERIA, TUBO DE PVC, REFORZADO, 4", PZA 6 MTS"). This character (used as shorthand for inches) is not escaped so will cause problems. I get some shifted cells when reading into a spreadsheet. It may be possible to do a search-and-replace for this sort of pattern to tidy up your data - or can you re-export them from the database?

Comment: @r2evans you are right. The issue with the extra `"` is truncating the file so I get nrow(csv) = 2188.